# read html text from cell with libreoffice basic

Tags: libreoffice-basic

For some reason I need retrive "html formated text" from cell in which calc sheet.
I had tried :

```
Sub Main
    Osheet = ThisComponent.Sheets.getByName("mySheet")
    oCell = oSheet.getCellrangeByName("D2")
    Print oCell.htmlText REM there is no htmltext property in cell instance
    REM holp output some thing like <p color="#ff0000">text in cell</p>
End Sub
```

Is's possible to do this?

-----------update-------------

[image]

as image show above. I change color and the font size in cell.
then I need to retrive "html text" from the cell with VBA.
if possible It should output:

```
<font size='12'>Hi !<font color='#ff0000'>every</font><font size='16'>body</font>.<font color='#0000ff'>Are</font> you OK?</font></font>
```

How to implement this function with VBA?

Comment: What is the result you get if you do this ?